# Unit Testing xUnit Asserting 2 Collections with Moq Interface

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd, xunit

Good day everyone,

I'm new in xunit and even in unit testing. I have a code here and I'm trying to assert two collection of list. But I have no idea how to assert and pass this test. Here's my code

```
    [Theory]
    [InlineData(1)]
    public void GetAllStudents_Exempt1(int number)
    {
        // arrange
        var studentRepo = new Mock<IStudentRepository>();
        var listOfStudents = new List<Student> { new Student { StudentId = 1, Firstname = "Firstname1", Lastname = "Firstname1" },
        new Student{StudentId=2, Firstname="Firstname2",Lastname="Lastname2"} };

        var getAllStudentDetailsExempt1 = studentRepo.Setup(s => s.GetStudents()).Returns(listOfStudents.Where(x => x.StudentId != number));

        var studentService = new StudentService(studentRepo.Object);

        // act
        var getStudentsDetails = studentService.ListOfStudentsExempt1(1);

        // assert
        // I don't have any idea how to assert
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First a few notes:

```
var getAllStudentDetailsExempt1 = studentRepo
    .Setup(s => s.GetStudents())
    .Returns(listOfStudents.Where(x => x.StudentId != number));
```

you don't need `var getAllStudentDetailsExempt1`, you can just setup your repo-mock...

```
studentRepo
    .Setup(s => s.GetStudents())
    .Returns(listOfStudents.Where(x => x.StudentId != number));
```

You probably want to change:

```
// act
var getStudentsDetails = studentService.ListOfStudentsExempt1(1);
```

to use the `number` variable...

```
// act
var getStudentsDetails = studentService.ListOfStudentsExempt1(number);
```

So then you can assert by checking some properties:

```
Assert.Equals(1, getStudentsDetails.Count);
Assert.Equals("FirstName1", getStudentsDetails.First().Firstname);
```

etc. etc.

Give it a shot!